# Testing fitness with push-ups, 1-2 mile run

Tags: assessment

Id like to know whats a simple way of testing fitness. The army seems to prefer push-ups, pull-ups, 2 mile run. But I wonder what happens to testing flexibility or respiratory capacity or peak force. Wouldnt these also be meaningful tests of fitness?

Answer (score 1):

Depending on your definition of “simple”, there are many evaluation protocols that can be used to measure a specific **aspect** of an individual's “fitness”.  These consist of:

- Cardiorespiratory efficiency (resting and exercise).
- Muscular strength and endurance.
- Muscle and joint flexibility.
- Body composition.

to name a few.  The answer will depend on what it is you're trying to test.  For example, the following lists some tests and what they evaluate.

[YMCA Sub-maximal Bicycle test](http://www.exrx.net/Testing/YMCACycleTest.html) – evaluates physical work capacity and estimates maximal oxygen uptake.

[Rockport Fitness Walking test](http://www.exrx.net/Calculators/Rockport.html) – assess cardiovascular fitness.

[Bench press test](http://www.exrx.net/Calculators/YBenchPress.html) – tests the endurance and strength of the chest and shoulders.

[Trunk Flexion/Sit and reach test](http://www.topendsports.com/testing/tests/sit-and-reach.htm) – measures flexibility of the lower back and hamstrings.

[Bioelectrical impedence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bioelectrical_impedance_analysis) – measures body composition and body fat.

The above are only a sample of the tests that are available.  Testing for 'fitness' means different things to different people.  There's no one test that provides a complete picture of an individual's level of fitness.  So, as was stated, you'll need to identify what it is you'd like to test, and, select an appropriate testing protocol.